# Cannot start/launch Android emulator in the AVD

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

When I try to launch the emulator from the AVD , I got this message :-

```
 Starting emulator for AVD 'Android_4.1'
 NAND: could not write file C:\Users\Hazem\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\TMP3E19.tmp, No space left on device
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delete some files in C:\ drive it is full that is the problem there isnt enough space to allocate to the emulator.

Comment: I know that C is full , I need to change the directory which that file needs to be created .

Comment: hmmm i dunno how to do that but yo could try to delete some files and create some files...Sorry that i couldnt be of any more help...

Answer (score 7):

Go to this location C:\Users\Hazem\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\ and you will see many files such as TMP3E19.tmp. Go ahead and deleted all of them. If your emulator is open, you may not be able to to delete all of them and just click on skip and delete as many as you can. If your emulator is closed, you will be able to delete all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to go local disk properties and click disk cleanup also make sure u have removed temp files and recycle bin items.it will remove all the dump files and your memory will be released..

Answer (score 0):

This happens because, you dont have free space in the drive where you are creating your Emulator, try deleting few items of that drive and it would get launched, make sure you have 1 gb (for precautions) data free in the drive. It worked for me